# How to put two ul next each other?

Tags: css

I have two ul and i need to put them in one row :
http://jsfiddle.net/2r5ER/207/ there is my fiddle what im trying to do is to put all in one row.Any suggestion?

```
 <nav>

     <div class="menu-topmenu-container">
       <ul id="menu-topmenu" class="menu">
          <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-53"><a href="#whatson">What’s On</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46"><a href="">Collections &amp; Research</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-10 current_page_item menu-item-52"><a href="http://muzej.ba/visiting-us/">Visiting Us</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50"><a href="">Learning</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-49"><a href="">Get Involved</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>       
     <ul class="second-row">
           <li><a href="">test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ONLINE SHOP</a></li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Something like this? [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2r5ER/208/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:auto;
}

nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    width:auto;
}
div.menu-topmenu-container{
  display:inline-block;

}
```

Should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Make it `display: inline` or `display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

You have the possibility to simply add `display:flex;` to `nav` like in the following example:

```css
nav {
  float: right;
  display:flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="menu-topmenu-container">
    <ul id="menu-topmenu" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-53"><a href="#whatson">What’s On</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46"><a href="">Collections &amp; Research</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-10 current_page_item menu-item-52"><a href="http://muzej.ba/visiting-us/">Visiting Us</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50"><a href="">Learning</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-49"><a href="">Get Involved</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>        
  <ul class="second-row">
    <li><a href="">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ONLINE SHOP</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

If you don't need the wrapping `<div class="menu-topmenu-container">` you can remove it!